# Matrix dimensionality checks at compile time

Tags: haskell

I was wondering whether is was possible to use the matrix type from `Data.Matrix` to construct another type with which it becomes possible to perform dimensionality checking at compile time.

E.g. I want to be able to write a function like:

```
mmult :: Matrix' r c -> Matrix' c r -> Matrix' r r
mmult = ...
```

However, I don't see how to do this since the arguments to a type constructor `Matrix'` would have to be types and not integer constants.

Comment: The defined type-level "integers": with `Nat` for example: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fin-0.1.1/docs/Data-Type-Nat.html So haskell "understands" integers at that level.

Comment: See for example here `V` for fixed sized arrays: https://github.com/ekmett/linear/blob/master/src/Linear/V.hs#L141-L146

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't see how to do this since the arguments to a type constructor `Matrix'` would have to be types and not integer constants

They do need to be *type-**level** values*, but not necessarily types. “Type-level” basically just means *known at compile-time*, but this also contains stuff that isn't really types. Types are in particular the type-level values of [kind `Type`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Kind.html#t:Type), but you can also have type-level strings or, indeed, [natural numbers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Nat).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

import Data.Matrix

newtype Matrix' (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) a
   = StaMat {getStaticSizeMatrix :: Matrix a}

mmult :: Num a => Matrix' n m a -> Matrix' l n a -> Matrix' l m a
mmult (StaMat f) (StaMat g) = StaMat $ multStd f g
```

I would remark that matrices are only a special case of a much more general mathematical concept, that of *linear maps between vector spaces*. And since vector spaces [can be seen as particular types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html), it actually makes a lot of sense to **not** use mere integers as the type-level tags, but the actual spaces. What you have then is a [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)), and it allows you to deal with both dynamic- and static size matrix/vector types, and can even be generalised to completely different spaces like infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

newtype StaVect (n :: Nat) a
  = StaVect {getStaticSizeVect :: Vector a}

data LinMap v w where
  StaMat :: Matrix a -> LinMap (StaVec n a) (StaVec m a)
  -- ...Add more constructors for mappings between other sorts of vector spaces...

linCompo :: LinMap v w -> LinMap u v -> LinMap u w
linCompo (StaMat f) (StaMat g) = StaMat $ multStd f g
```

The [`linearmap-category` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category) pursues this direction.

Comment: One question: can I perform arithmetic on Nats? I.e. have a function like `Matrix' n m a -> Matrix' (2*n) m a`?

Comment: You can to basic arithmetic, but it easily confuses the typechecker. (It will not accept anything where the types really don't match, but may also complain with stuff like `couldn't match 1+a with a+1`.)